# GEKKO gives TypeError: must be real number, not GK_Operators, I have several approaches that is recommended

Tags: python, gekko

I am trying to solve an NLP with GEKKO, however I have a few problem while implementing the Python code. The model that I am trying to solve is pretty trivial, I am trying to find the optimal point that has minimum loss function value in a 3D convex set.

```
def calculateLossFunction(h, x, y, lmbd, n):
    sum = 0
    x_star = np.dot(np.transpose(lmbd), x)
    y_star = np.dot(np.transpose(lmbd), y)

    for i in range(n):
        RNJ = math.sqrt((x_star - x[i]) ** 2 + (y_star - y[i]) ** 2)
        P = 1 / (math.degrees(math.atan(h[i] / RNJ)))
        sum += A * P + B
    return sum
```

This is the objective function for my problem and I am using this as follows

```
m = GEKKO(remote=True)
eq = m.Param()
H = [500, 1500, 2500]
locations = np.array([[1, 2],
                      [2, 3],
                      [3, 1]])
XN = locations[:, 0]
YN = locations[:, 1]
n = len(locations)

lambdas = m.Array(m.Var,n,lb=0, ub = 1, value = 0)
lambdas[0].value = 1


m.Minimize(calculateLossFunction(H, XN, YN, lambdas, n))
m.Equation(sum(lambdas) == 1)
m.solve(disp=True) # solve on public server
#Results
print('')
print('Results')
print('x1: ' + str(lambdas[0].value))
print('x2: ' + str(lambdas[1].value))
print('x3: ' + str(lambdas[2].value))
```

The thing is, although I've checked similar problems that are raised in Stack Overflow and tried to mimic the recommended solutions, at this point seems like I cannot figure out what is wrong because above code gives the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    m.Minimize(calculateLossFunction(H, XN, YN, lambdas, n))
  File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\nonlinear.py", line 13, in calculateLossFunction
    RNJ = math.sqrt((x_star - x[i]) ** 2 + (y_star - y[i]) ** 2)
TypeError: must be real number, not GK_Operators
```

I've also read the documentation but couldn't find any solution.
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Just before the line `RNJ = math.sqrt(...`, what is `type(x_star)` or `type(x[i])` ? Or the type of the thing of which you are taking the root? I'd imagine that they are numbers, but it says they are GK_Operators (?)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `gekko` functions `m.sqrt()` and `m.atan()` instead of `math.sqrt()` and `math.atan()`. The `TypeError: must be real number, not GK_Operators` is from the `math` function. There is no `math.degrees()` equivalent in `gekko`, so use `360.0/(2.0*np.pi)` for the conversion. Gekko uses gradient-based optimizers that require overloading of the operators and functions for automatic differentiation to provide exact 1st and 2nd derivatives of constraints and objectives. Some functions are compatible such as `np.dot()` while others do not return a symbolic solution, such as `math.sqrt()`. Here is a complete problem that solves successfully:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
A = 1.0; B=0.0
def calculateLossFunction(h, x, y, lmbd, n):
    sum = 0
    x_star = np.dot(np.transpose(lmbd), x)
    y_star = np.dot(np.transpose(lmbd), y)

    for i in range(n):
        RNJ = m.sqrt((x_star - x[i]) ** 2 + (y_star - y[i]) ** 2)
        P = 1 / (360.0*(m.atan(h[i] / RNJ)/(2.0*np.pi)))
        sum += A * P + B
    return sum
m = GEKKO(remote=True)
eq = m.Param()
H = [500, 1500, 2500]
locations = np.array([[1, 2],
                      [2, 3],
                      [3, 1]])
XN = locations[:, 0]
YN = locations[:, 1]
n = len(locations)
lambdas = m.Array(m.Var,n,lb=0, ub = 1, value = 0)
lambdas[0].value = 1
m.Minimize(calculateLossFunction(H, XN, YN, lambdas, n))
m.Equation(sum(lambdas) == 1)
m.solve(disp=True) # solve on public server
print('Results')
print('x1: ' + str(lambdas[0].value))
print('x2: ' + str(lambdas[1].value))
print('x3: ' + str(lambdas[2].value))
```

Solution with sample `A=1.0` and `B=0.0` values:

```
Results
x1: [0.99999702144]
x2: [1.9787728836e-06]
x3: [9.9978717975e-07]
```

and the solver output:

```
Number of Iterations....: 113

                                   (scaled)                 (unscaled)
Objective...............:   3.3346336759950239e-02    3.3346336759950239e-02
Dual infeasibility......:   8.4348140936638533e-07    8.4348140936638533e-07
Constraint violation....:   0.0000000000000000e+00    0.0000000000000000e+00
Complementarity.........:   1.0000010522025397e-11    1.0000010522025397e-11
Overall NLP error.......:   8.4348140936638533e-07    8.4348140936638533e-07


Number of objective function evaluations             = 1237
Number of objective gradient evaluations             = 114
Number of equality constraint evaluations            = 1237
Number of inequality constraint evaluations          = 0
Number of equality constraint Jacobian evaluations   = 114
Number of inequality constraint Jacobian evaluations = 0
Number of Lagrangian Hessian evaluations             = 113
Total CPU secs in IPOPT (w/o function evaluations)   =      0.067
Total CPU secs in NLP function evaluations           =      0.034

EXIT: Optimal Solution Found.
 
 The solution was found.
 
 The final value of the objective function is   3.334633675995024E-002
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  IPOPT (v3.12)
 Solution time  :   0.131699999998091      sec
 Objective      :   3.334633675995024E-002
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

Trigonometric functions sometimes need constraints on the variables to ensure that a `NaN` value is not returned or to make a solution unique (such as `cos(np.pi)` and `cos(-np.pi)`.

Comment: Sir, Thank you for your explanation. In the 
`m.Equation(sum(lambdas) == 1)` 
part, I'd like to add a constraint about the summation of all decision variables must be equal to 1, can I use Python's sum() method or does GEKKO have an equivalent?
@John Hedengren

Comment: You can use either the Python `sum()` or the gekko `m.sum()`. The advantage of the gekko sum is that it can build larger symbolic expressions and generally solves more efficiently.